# set install location doesn't work

Tags: android, android-sdcard, adk

i'm trying to change default install location of my android device to sd cad, because the internal memory of device isn't enough, and also when i i go to apps info i never see the option move app to sd card..so i downloaded adt bundle, updated my device drivers, and then tried the command

```
 adb devices
```

my device was showed successfully, after that i did the

```
 adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

the command was executed successfully and then after that, to be sure that this worked i did the

```
 adb shell pm get-install-location
```

and it showed me that the install location is the external(2), so i guess i did all the steps right, but when i go to install an app i still get the message that there is not enough memory on internal device...whats the problem because it pissed me off...